# JSF - Session Bean restart on logout and login

Tags: jsp, session, jsf

I have a web application with a backing bean which has the context of the current logged in user. It is implemented on JSF.

When the user logs out he is forwarded to a login screen (in another JSP page). I would like the current session to be erased when that happens and a new one to be created the next time the user logs in and enters the application.

My question is - how do you delete a session? (I guess the new session will be created automatically the next time the user enters the link)

This is kinda newb i guess, but I couldn't find a solution for this.
Thanks for the Help!

Comment: HttpSession#invalidate() invalidates current session

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
((HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
   .getExternalContext().getSession(false)).invalidate();
```

Comment: And the next time I login the session will be created again?

Answer (score 1):

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();

Comment: 7 years later... :)